# Error when Trying to use Try-Catch blocks within excel VBA to get inner exceptions

Tags: excel, vba, exception, try-catch

I am working through excel and VBA. I am trying to get the inner exception from an automation exception, but to start off I need to get try catch blocks working in the first place. It looks like I've exactly replicated the syntax from the microsoft documentation. Here is the code:

```
Try
    Set sm = CreateObject("SpectrumManager.Application")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox ("Can't Create Object") 'placeholder
    'I want to get the inner exception from ex here
End Try
```

The error message at End Try is this: "Expected: If or Select or Sub or Function or Property or Type or With or Enum or end of statement"
The error message at the Catch is this: "Expected: end of statement"

What am I doing wrong? thanks for the help in advance.
edit: I realize now that vba does not support try-catch blocks. That leads me to the question, is there any way to get an inner exception from the original exception that was sent? Or is that information lost when it is converted into a vba Error?

Comment: vba doesn't support try catch. VB.net does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA + Excel + Try Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638867/vba-excel-try-catch)

Comment: Any Microsoft documentation that is about "Visual Basic" is filed under .NET and is about VB.NET; [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/) is the docs.microsoft for VBA.

Comment: Are you programming in VB.NET or VBA? The compile error that I'd expect in VBA would be "Sub or Function not defined" on the `Try` line.  If it got past that, it would fail with a generic "Syntax error" on the `Catch` line.

Answer (score 11):

VBA doesn't support Try Catch. You can use error handling or more simply

```
On Error Resume Next
Set sm = CreateObject("SpectrumManager.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If sm Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't Create Object"
End If
```

---

A simple error handling routine might look like:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim sm As Object
    On Error GoTo errhand
    Set sm = CreateObject("SpectrumManager.Application")
    'other code
    Exit Sub
errhand:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 429
        MsgBox "Can't Create Object"
        'Case... other errors
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: So I'm assuming based on your response that It would not be possible to get the inner exception from the original exception that was sent. Thanks for the response.

Comment: what do you mean by that? The exception is basically the Case  number with associated err.Description in the error handler of the bottom version. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are willing to consider commercial third party as options, there is the option to buy [vbWatchDog](https://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.asp), which enables a form of Try/Catch pattern with VBA. A possible sample:

```
Public Sub Derp(Faceplant As Boolean)
  If Faceplant = False Then
    ErrEx.DoFinally
  End If

  Debug.Print 1 / 0

ErrEx.Catch 91
  Debug.Print "I didn't set something on fire...."
ErrEx.CatchAll
  Debug.Print "Welp. I failed."
ErrEx.Finally
  Debug.Print "Goodbye, cruel world."
End Sub
```

[Relevant documentation](https://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog/introduction.htm)

Note: I'm a customer of vbWatchDog.