# "Unexpected Error" (Can I fix it, or possibly have VBA "x" out of it?)

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have some VBA code that refreshes//saves//closes my Excel reports in the morning.

Unfortunately, some of the reports are throwing an "unexpected error" which interrupts the script.

[image]

If I simply "x" out of the Unexpected Error message, the script continues to run smoothly.

**MY QUESTION:**

1) How can I fix the error?  (I copied the details below)

2) If I can't fix the error, **is there a way to have VBA "x" out of the message for me?** (VBS script code at very bottom)

Thank you for any help you can provide.  I'm fairly new to VBA but am really falling in love with it.

Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:

> Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B
>   (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))

Stack Trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Interop.NativeExcelInteropUtils.ValidateResult(Int32
>   result, Int32[] expectedValues)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Win32.NativeWinFormsTaskPaneFunctions.IsTaskPaneVisible(NativeTaskPaneType type, IntPtr uiFrame)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.TaskPaneControls.QueriesAndConnectionsTaskPaneControl.EnsureWorkbookConnections()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.TaskPaneControls.QueriesAndConnectionsTaskPaneControl.TryInitializeInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.TaskPaneControls.TaskPaneControl.TryInitialize(ITaskPane
>   officeTaskPane)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.CustomTaskPaneManager.TryCreateTaskPane(IWindowContext
>   windowContext, ITaskPane& taskPane)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.CustomTaskPaneManager.TryGetOrCreateTaskPane(IWindowContext
>   windowContext, ITaskPane& taskPane)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.CustomTaskPaneManagers.UpdateQueriesTaskPaneVisibility(IWindowContext
>   windowContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelEventHandler.PerformPeriodicUpdate(IEnumerable`1
>   queriesTaskPaneVisibilityUpdateWindows)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeEventHandler.b__11_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler
>   exceptionHandler, Action action)
>
> Stack Trace Message: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at

> Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
>   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String
>   message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String
>   messageDetail)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle
>   activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo,
>   Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler
>   exceptionHandler, Action action)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelCallbackManager.InvokeAndReturnHResult(Action
>   action)

InnerException.Stack Trace Message:

> Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))
>
> InnerException.Stack Trace:
>
> InnerException.Invocation Stack Trace:    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception
>   e, String prefix)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String
>   message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String
>   messageDetail)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle
>   activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo,
>   Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler
>   exceptionHandler, Action action)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelCallbackManager.InvokeAndReturnHResult(Action
>   action)

Supports Premium Content:
True

---

VBA CODE:

```
Dim objExcel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Analyst_Reporting\Automation\PIECES AUTOMATION BOOK.xlsm") 'THIS OPENS THE MASTER EXCEL BOOK 
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.APDPIECES"  'THIS OPENS THE FIRST REPORT
set wbk = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.helloworld" 'THIS REFRESHES THE REPORT
wbk.save
wbk.close(0)

objExcel.Run"THISWORKBOOK.APDTIMESTAMP"   'TIMESTAMP IN THE MASTER BOOK 
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.SAVEBOOK"      
objExcel.Run"ThisWorkbook.PIPPIECES"
set wbk = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.helloworld"
wbk.save
wbk.close(0)

objExcel.Run"ThisWorkbook.PIPTIMESTAMP"
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.SAVEBOOK"
```

Comment: look up "vba on error"

Comment: Will do.  However, aren't the vba "on error" statements only used for VBA error messages?  

This particular error message seems to be an "excel error message".  Thanks so much.

Comment: It seems it is a COM error. So likely in a call to run. Could your macro be in the master workbook? if so there would be no need to call run to execute the other ones...

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638867/vba-excel-try-catch/44638899

Comment: Also try to find which run fails. You may need some delays between the calls !?